# Parsing inserted json object android

Tags: java, android, json

Sorry for my english. I try parsing inserted json, in my example i have this json:

```
{
    "myTable": {
        "1": {
            "type": "1",
            "category": "1",
            "body": {
                "2": {
                    "id": "2",
                    "device_name": "test 1"
                },
                "5": {
                    "id": "5",
                    "device_name": "test 2"
                }
            }
        },
        "2": {
            "type": "2",
            "category": "1",
            "body": {
                "6": {
                    "id": "6",
                    "device_name": "test 3"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Its json object to json object. This put me stumped. Bellow my try code parse this json

```
JSONObject sensorTypes = json.getJSONObject("myTable");

                if(sensorTypes.length() > 0) {
                    Iterator<String> iterasensorTypes = sensorTypes.keys();

                    while(iterasensorTypes.hasNext()) {
                        String currentKey = iterasensorTypes.next();
                        JSONObject obj = sensorTypes.optJSONObject(currentKey);

                        if(obj != null) {
                            Log.e("type", obj.getString("type"));
                            Log.e("category", obj.getString("category"));

                            JSONObject sensor = json.getJSONObject("body");
                            if(sensor.length() > 0) {
                                Iterator<String> iteratorSensor = sensor.keys();

                                while( iteratorSensor.hasNext() ) {
                                    String currentKeySensor = iteratorSensor.next();
                                    JSONObject objSensor = sensor.optJSONObject(currentKeySensor);

                                    if(objSensor != null) {
                                        Log.e("device_name", objSensor.getString("device_name"));
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }


                    }

                }
```

And i have this:

org.json.JSONException: No value for `body`

**UPD:**

My log:

```
E/type﹕ 1
E/category﹕ 1
E/ get﹕ org.json.JSONException: No value for body
```

Comment: Post your full  `log`

Comment: @Clairvoyant thanks for answer, i update my qestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `json.getJSONObject("body");` instead of `obj.getJSONObject("body");`, `json` is the top object, the one with the key `myTable`. `body` is inside the children of `myTable`, the ones you iterate through and reference using the `obj` object `JSONObject obj = sensorTypes.optJSONObject(currentKey);`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
JSONObject sensor = json.getJSONObject("body");
```

use

```
JSONObject sensor = obj.getJSONObject("body"); //changed to obj from json
```